# Single quotes with whitespace in double quotes

Tags: html

Hy!
I want an alert windows with whitespace and single quote inside, like this:

```
<button onclick=alert("I'm here")> Click me </button>
```

In documentation says: You can use quotes inside a string, as long as they don't match the quotes surrounding the string.
Unfortunately don't work, if I use this form (with no whitespace), code is works:

```html
<button onclick=alert("I'm_here")> Click me </button>
```

I tried:

```
<button onclick="alert("I'm here")"> Click me </button>
```

but don't works . .

Comment: Avoid intrinsic event attributes, [bind event handlers with JS instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape those quotes like so:

```
<button onclick="alert('I\'m here')">Click me</button>
```

Note the back slashes.

[See here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp)

Comment: alert without whitespace why don't need escape character?

Comment: I'm sorry, your English is quite bad. Can you rephrase what you are asking?

Comment: if the phrase from alert window don't has whitespace why don't need escape character before single quote?

Comment: Your alert string output starts with a single quote and must end with a single quote. If you put a single quote in your string such as the above instance but the intention is not to end the quote, it must be escaped with a back slash to show the interpreter that we don't want to end the string there but to ignore it. Other characters like whitespace don't need to be escaped because they alone don't tell javascript to end the string.

Comment: I asked the second code:    <button onclick=alert("I'm_here")> Click me </button>

Comment: `<button onclick="alert('I\'m_here')"> Click me </button>` - Same rule applies as the answer above. You just neglected to wrap the property value with quotes.

Comment: my question is why this code work without escape character:  <button onclick=alert("I'm_here")> Click me </button>

Comment: Because you are not opening the string with a single quote. You are opening with a double and closing with a double so it ignored the single.

Comment: yes, but if the string has whitespace the single don't ignored . .

Comment: I edited the question, I put the second code in codeSnipped and works but the   <button onclick=alert("I'm here")> code don't works. The only diference is the whitespace.

Comment: No, the difference is you are not wrapping your value for the property.

`onclick="alert('I\'m here')"`

Comment: Have you even tried the answer above? It gives you EXACTLY what you are requesting in your edited question.